# Is there a way to determine a node's status through API calls?

Tags: ingress

I'm planning to build a device that changes color from blue to green that can change color be left at a node to publicly announce node status. How would I get that information from Ingress?

Is there an API or something I can poll to just get a specific node's status?

Failing that, will Ingress run in a virtualized environment and accept GPS coordinates fed through the emulator?

I'd like to leave the device in the window of a building at a node so the node's possession status can be seen by players at ground zero.

Answer (score 4):

That would be really cool, but unfortunately at the moment it is against the [ToS](http://www.ingress.com/terms).

> In addition to the restrictions set out in the Google Terms of Service, unless you have received prior written authorization from Google (or, as applicable, from the provider of particular Content), you shall not:
>
> ..............
>
> (d) extract, scrape, or index the Products or Content (including information about users or game play);

So the answer is no, there is no API and scraping the data from the Intel or Scanner is forbidden.

I have seen people get banned for automatically refreshing the Intel Map often (=for taking screenshots during a larger operation).